# passing variables from python to bash shell script via os.system

Tags: python, bash

In the following code, I construct a variable $probe1 that I want to then pass to a bash script. I the toy example below, the output is blank, i.e. $probe1 is not recognized the the bash shell script within the os.system call. What needs to be done?

```
for line1 in datfile:
    datmat=datmat+[line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')]
        probe=datmat[i][0]
        snp1=datmat[i][2]
    probe1='permprobes'+probe+'pheno.pphe'
    os.system('echo $probe1')
```

Comment: `probe1 = '...'` sets a Python variable. It has no connection to Bash whatsoever.

Comment: Is there some way to carry over a variable from python to the bash shell? That's essentially my question.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I'm using python to extract some variable names, which I then need to pass as arguments to a program that's executed from a bash script. Therefore, I need to export the string $probe1 to a bash shell (I'm just using echo as a simple example to illustrate the problem)

Comment: But why do you need the variables? Why don't you just quote the arguments and pass them directly to the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like this is what you are trying to do:

```
In [2]: os.environ['probe1'] = 'hello'

In [3]: os.system('echo $probe1')
hello
```

But I have no idea why you would like to do this ...

Comment: I'm using python to extract some variable names from a data file, which I then need to pass to a bash shell script to run in another program. The example with echo is just a "toy" script to illustrate the problem of moving a variable from python into a bash shell.

Comment: @user1815498 Maybe you can use a `pipe` to do that: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: In any case, the os.environ[ ] solution you propose solves my problem.  Thank you for the pipe reference, it will come in handy when I need to pass multiple variables from python to the shell.

Answer (score 4):

```
os.system('echo {0}'.format(probe1))
```

probe1 is a python variable, not a shell variable.

```
os.environ['probe1'] = probe1
```

will set the bash environment variable to the python variable contents.  Once the python script exits though, the environment variable goes away.

Comment: I know that, my question is how I can transfer a python variable to the bash shell.